# How to Make loop for several gam models with various k values

Tags: r

I want to run different gam models with the combination of various k values (k=i,k=j,k=l,k=m,k=n and range for i=4,5,6,7,8 and same for j,l,m,n) at a time, using R studio. Actually, I need AIC of each model for various k's.
I have started with this code:

```
    library(mgcv)
    u<-c(4:8)
    v<-c(4:8)
    w<-c(4:8)
    x<-c(4:8)
    y<-c(4:8)
    n<-1
    aic<-0
    kt<-""
    for(i in u){for(j in v){for (l in w){for(m in x){for(n in y)
    {fit<-gam(dat$y~dat$x1+s(pc1,bs="cr",k=i)
    +s(pc2,bs="cr",k=j)+s(pc3,bs="cr",k=l)
    +s(pc4,bs="cr",k=m)+s(pc5,bs="cr",k=n)
    +as.factor(dat$x2),data=dat,family=poisson,method="REML")
    aic[n]<-AIC(fit)
    kt[n]<-paste("A",i,"B",j,"C",l,"D",m,"E",n)
    n<-n+1}}}}
    result<-data.frame(aic,kt)
    result
```

And got this output

```
           aic                  kt
    1    0.000                    
    2       NA                <NA>
    3       NA                <NA>
    4 8363.725 A 8 B 8 C 8 D 8 E 4
    5 8354.917 A 8 B 8 C 8 D 8 E 5
    6 8355.699 A 8 B 8 C 8 D 8 E 6
    7 8356.166 A 8 B 8 C 8 D 8 E 7
    8 8356.281 A 8 B 8 C 8 D 8 E 8
```

I think I did some mistake here with the code. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Did you try `print(extractAIC(fit))` ?

Comment: No, Actually I did the edited code above. But the output gives only 5 AIC!

Comment: Why are you changing the value of n at the bottom of the loop?  You already have for(n in y) in the declaration.

Comment: So, you are indexing by n but also using n as a lcv.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your data and have not run this solution to see if it works.  You use the variable n for two different things.  Here, I change the name of the main counter from n to nn.

```
library(mgcv)
u<-c(4:8)
v<-c(4:8)
w<-c(4:8)
x<-c(4:8)
y<-c(4:8)
nn<-1
aic<-0
kt<-""
for(i in u){for(j in v){for (l in w){for(m in x){for(n in y)
{fit<-gam(dat$y~dat$x1+s(pc1,bs="cr",k=i)
+s(pc2,bs="cr",k=j)+s(pc3,bs="cr",k=l)
+s(pc4,bs="cr",k=m)+s(pc5,bs="cr",k=n)
+as.factor(dat$x2),data=dat,family=poisson,method="REML")
aic[nn]<-AIC(fit)
kt[nn]<-paste("A",i,"B",j,"C",l,"D",m,"E",n)
nn<-nn+1}}}}
result<-data.frame(aic,kt)
result
```

Comment: Exactly! it's the problem with describing n and nn. I run your code and it works! Thank you!! Can you please tell one thing more, how can I get the list of minimum AIC values with kt. At first I find the minimum aic as: min(result$aic), it is 8385.17. Then try, subset(res$kt,aic=="8385.17"). But it did not work.

Comment: Use the which function to get the index then use that.